# ggplot2: Decrease size of regression line equation and R^2 in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The way to add a regression line equation and R^2 in ggplot2 is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27959418). However, I want to decrease the size of the font of the line equation and R^2 in the plot. Is this possible? Also would it be possible to decrease the size of a data point on the plot. It is hard to get a good plot when I have many points since the size of the point is not very small.

Comment: Can you add some reproducible example, so that you can help people help you.

Comment: Try to add `size` in `stat_smooth_func`.